# PHP echo results under single date header

Tags: php

I have a large database that I am querying. There are multiple results that share the same "Date". SO, I might have 5 results today and 8 results yesterday and so on.

I echo the result so that each article has the "date" below the title right now. But, I am searching how to show the DATE HEADER and then the article headlines below each date that is grouped.

SO:

**September 19, 2016**

- Article 1 Title
- Article 2 Title
- Article 3 Title
- Article 4 Title

**September 17, 2016**

- Article 1_1 Title
- Article 2_1 Title
- Article 3_1 Title

... so on.

Here is a snapshot of my MYSQL. Thanks super mucho in advanced NINJAS!!

[image]

Code is below:

```
<?php do { ?>

<b><?php echo date('M. j, Y', ($row_Recordset2['date'])); ?></b><br />
<b><a href="/full.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset2['id']; ?>"><?php echo stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($row_Recordset2['title'])); ?></a></b><br />
<?php echo (stripslashes(str_replace("{nl}", "<br />", $row_Recordset2['short']))); ?>


<?php } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>
```

Comment: Maybe it's time to show code?

Comment: Add your php code please

Comment: duh,.. forgot to add it when I hit publish. It is up now. whoops.

Comment: Your code style is somewhat lacking. You might consider posting this on codereview.stackexchange.com for some pointers.

Comment: Great thinking. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

1) Do not use do..while, use only while
2)

```
<?php $current_date = '';
    while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)){
      if($current_date !== $row_Recordset2['date']){
        echo '<b>' . date('M. j, Y', ($row_Recordset2['date'])) . '</b>';
        $current_date = $row_Recordset['date'];
    }
      echo "<b><a href=\"/full.php?id=$row_Recordset2[id]\">".     stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($row_Recordset2['title'])) . "</a></b><br />" .
      (stripslashes(str_replace("{nl}", "<br />", $row_Recordset2['short'])));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is working now with no errors.  However, it is still showing multiple "same dates" .. Is that because date needs to be converted to UNIX time ? See image above for database DATE format ? Also, there might be results echoed that only have one date too! Thanks NINJA!!